# "And" method for many to many value list in django models

Tags: python, django, model, relation

models:

```
class CompanyOptionalPrice(models.Model):
    first_units = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False, blank=False)
    last_units = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False, blank=False)
    units_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, null=False, blank=False, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, null=False, blank=False, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name="product_company_optional_price")
    units = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo1 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    photo2 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    photo3 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    photo4 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    photo5 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    photo6 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="products_photos/")
    optional_detail = models.ManyToManyField(OptionalDetails, related_name='op_detail')
    cdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class OptionalDetails(models.Model):
        detail = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', null=True)
        optional_features = models.ForeignKey(OptionalFeatures)
        cdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

controller:

```
def get_company_optional_price(request):
    cop = request.GET['cop']
    pid = request.GET['pid']
    cop_list2 = []
    cop_list = str(cop).split('-')
    filters = Q()
    for cop_item in cop_list:
        if cop_item != '' and cop_item != '0':
            cop_list2.append(int(cop_item))
            print cop_list2
            filters = filters | Q(optional_detail=int(cop_item))
    print filters
    order = CompanyOptionalPrice.objects.filter(filters, product=int(pid)).distinct().prefetch_related('optional_detail')
    print order
    data = serializers.serialize("json", order)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="text/json")
```

output:

```
[1]
[1, 4]
[1, 4, 5]
(OR: (AND: ), ('optional_detail', 1), ('optional_detail', 4), ('optional_detail', 5))
[<CompanyOptionalPrice: CompanyOptionalPrice object>, <CompanyOptionalPrice: CompanyOptionalPrice object>]
```

Result:

```
[{"pk": 6, "model": "list.companyoptionalprice", "fields": {"product": 1, "last_units": 29, "photo3": "", "optional_detail": [2, 3, 5], "discount_price": "89.00", "photo2": "", "first_units": 77, "cdate": "2015-08-07T09:08:02.421Z", "photo1": "", "photo6": "", "photo4": "", "photo5": "", "units": 85, "units_price": "79.00"}}, 

{"pk": 4, "model": "list.companyoptionalprice", "fields": {"product": 1, "last_units": 5, "photo3": "", "optional_detail": [1, 4, 5], "discount_price": "69.00", "photo2": "", "first_units": 10, "cdate": "2015-08-07T08:43:12.196Z", "photo1": "", "photo6": "", "photo4": "", "photo5": "", "units": 33, "units_price": "35.00"}}]
```

hi, i need "sql and method" for many to many filter on django. I use this algorithm but doesnt work. my result must be ;

```
 {"pk": 4, "model": "list.companyoptionalprice", "fields": {"product": 1, "last_units": 5, "photo3": "", "optional_detail": [1, 4, 5], "discount_price": "69.00", "photo2": "", "first_units": 10, "cdate": "2015-08-07T08:43:12.196Z", "photo1": "", "photo6": "", "photo4": "", "photo5": "", "units": 33, "units_price": "35.00"}}]
```

value list is [1,4,5] but result have to [2,3,5] in data

Comment: To start things off, you need `Q(optional_detail__pk=int(cop_item))` because your `cop_item` is an integer, and you are trying to compare it with a related object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly. So `request.GET['cop']` is `1-4-5`?
If so, what you're doing is "Get the CompanyOptionalPrice rows for which the optional_detail is 1, 4 or 5". That is what the `|` is for when used qith `Q(...)`, making OR queries.

If what you want is an `AND` query for `[1, 4, 5]`, you need to do

```
q1 = Q(...)
q2 = Q(...)
q = q1 & q2
```

If what you want instead is "Get the CompanyOptionalPrice rows for which the optional_detail is NOT 1, 4 nor 5", you might want to use `.exclude(...)` instead of `.filter(...)`.

However, I see that a 5 is repeated in your desired input and output... is that a typo or how should a SQL query do "get all in this list" or "get all NOT in this list" if one element is common to both? That is confusing.